# Why is the Default Commercial and Default Transactional HTML Footer are not showing the same code when doing Preview and Test?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, send-email, admin, send-an-email

We created a custom HTML Footer, we inserted it in the Account Settings, and selected the "Custom" as the HTML Footer.

Now when I do preview and test, Default Commercial is showing the Custom HTML, but the Default Transactional is not showing the custom HTML, any reasons why is this happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following!
1) Make sure you have selected the correct DELIVERY PROFILE for your 
**Default Transactional** Send classification as below.
[image]

2) Make sure to the correct Deliver profile and send classification is selected while you are previewing in content builder.

[image]